# Ubuntu Core and Docker

Tags: raspberrypi, docker, ubuntu-core

The default install of Ubuntu Core on my RPI doesn’t appear to have docker installed.  Does anyone know how I can get docker and docker-compose up and running?

Comment: No release of Ubuntu includes pre-installed docker. Ubuntu Core is snap-only (no debs), so try `sudo snap install docker`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No release or official variant of Ubuntu - including Ubuntu Core - has Docker pre-installed or shipped with it.

Unlike other versions of Ubuntu, Ubuntu Core runs on snaps only, so you should run `sudo snap install docker` to install Docker.